# Which difference between /etc/aliases and virtual_alias_maps in Postfix?

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

Which difference between /etc/aliases and virtual_alias_maps in Postfix and where should I put aliases from local accounts to virtual user accounts (i.e. from root to postmaster@example.com)?

Comment: related [Confused about alias_maps and virtual_alias_maps](http://serverfault.com/questions/644306/confused-about-alias-maps-and-virtual-alias-maps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/etc/aliases is for compatibility with sendmail and is processed only by postfix/local delivery agent. Local LDA is used for domains on mydestination. The query is only for user local part (e.g. johndoe) as the awnser.

virtual_alias_maps is always processed and the query is by full email (e.g. johndoe@example.com) as the awnser.